# Find the percentage of people who are infected by cooties

Tags: probability

The Department of Health wishes to determine the percentage, $p$, of the general population who are infected by Cooties during a recent outbreak. The test for Cooties is known to be $99\%$ accurate given that a patient is infected and $90\%$ accurate given that a patient is not infected. The results of the tests are returning at $15\%$ positive.

Find $p$.

Let $P(A) =$ Accuracy and $P(I) =$ Infected

We know $P(A|I)=.99, P(A|I^C)=.9$

we want to find $p$ which is the percentage people who have cooties and I'm unsure of how to solve for I here.

Comment: $0.99 (p) + 0.1 (1-p) = 0.15$

Comment: I thought I was done after $I$, but I guess I need to find the total number of people tested. would I just do $P(A|I)+P(A^c|I^c)=.15$? NVM this gives me 1 = .15... I think I'm stuck @DougM

Comment: we have two groups, the true positives and the false positives.  And together they make up 15% of the sample

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Drug_testing for an almost identical computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p$ of the population is infected with the cooties. Then, when someone is tested, the probability that they have it is $p$, and the probability that they do not is $1-p$. Additionally, the probability that a person with the cooties will be correctly identified as a carrier is $0.99$, so the probability that a patient has the cooties and it detected is $0.99p$. The probability that a person without the cooties will be identified incorrectly as a carrier is $0.1$, so the probability that some randomly selected person does not have the cooties but it said to have them is $0.1(1-p)$. Then the total probability that the test results are positive on some randomly selected person is
$$0.99p+0.1(1-p)$$
Since the results are $15\%$ positive, we can set this equal to $0.15$ and solve for $p$:
$$0.99p+0.1(1-p)=0.15$$
$$0.99p-0.1p+0.1=0.15$$
$$0.89p=0.05$$
$$p=\frac{0.05}{0.89}$$
$$p=\frac{0.05}{0.89}$$
$$p\approx 0.0562$$
So about $5.62\%$ of the population carries the cooties.